# Reading Dates as column names Numpy genfromtxt

Tags: python, date, csv, numpy

I want to create a numpy array from a csv file. The data is comma separated but looks like this:

```
seqid   9/19/2009   9/26/2009   10/3/2009
4315      228046      227475      239080
19866     22241       27211       25313
23436     23576       23678       24687
23593     58074       61569       58564
23609     334673      313980      246823
```

I would like to preserve my column names as these dates, currently I'm using code:

```
mcvs = np.genfromtxt('csvfile.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)
```

When I use `names=True` I get a 1 column array back of the type `void`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Operating on your sample (using white space as delimiter), I get a 1d structured array with 4 fields.  The field names are the dates, stripped of the `/` character.

```
In [245]: np.genfromtxt(txt,dtype=None,names=True)
Out[245]: 
array([(4315, 228046, 227475, 239080), (19866, 22241, 27211, 25313),
       (23436, 23576, 23678, 24687), (23593, 58074, 61569, 58564),
       (23609, 334673, 313980, 246823)], 
      dtype=[('seqid', '<i4'), ('9192009', '<i4'), ('9262009', '<i4'), ('1032009', '<i4')])
```

'columns/fields' are accessed by field name:

```
In [252]: data['9192009']
Out[252]: array([228046,  22241,  23576,  58074, 334673])
```

(I'll look at the removed character in a bit)

`type` isn't a useful test of structured array elements.  Use `dtype`:

```
In [247]: type(data[0])
Out[247]: numpy.void

In [248]: data.dtype
Out[248]: dtype([('seqid', '<i4'), ('9192009', '<i4'), ('9262009', '<i4'), ('1032009', '<i4')])
```

---

The `deletechars` parameter lets me control whether `/` is removed or not:

```
In [250]: np.genfromtxt(txt,dtype=None,names=True,deletechars='')
Out[250]: 
array([(4315, 228046, 227475, 239080), (19866, 22241, 27211, 25313),
       (23436, 23576, 23678, 24687), (23593, 58074, 61569, 58564),
       (23609, 334673, 313980, 246823)], 
      dtype=[('seqid', '<i4'), ('9/19/2009', '<i4'), ('9/26/2009', '<i4'), ('10/3/2009', '<i4')])
```